# including several beamer presentations as minimized images in a frame

Tags: beamer

I want to have a frame in such a way that it contains, say, 4 small images. Each one of these images is the first frame of a beamer presentation, so that when I click to the small image it zooms to full screen, appearing the beamer presentation. Once this presentation is finished, it minimizes to the small image, so then I can proceed by clicking the 2nd small image and start with the 2nd beamer presentation, and so on...is it possible to get such frame of images that are beamer presentations??.

Comment: Do you the 4 other presentations already made?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Werner yes they are already done. Gonzalo' s answer is actually very accurate, but I would like a nice transition when clicking each presentation. I mean, it should zoom out to the full screen mode in an animated manner, that is, it should get slowly bigger until it reaches the full screen mode, and once this secondary presentation is over, the image should come back to its minimized image slowly, in an animated way, and then go to the next presentation and so on.

Comment: For that you would need to program some transition, perhaps with Javascript (beyond the scope of this Q&A). Moreover, you may find that it only works in one viewer (say Adobe), but not another.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible: the idea is quite simple: (in the following example, the four presentations will be called `beamer-1.pdf`, `beamer-2.pdf`, `beamer-3.pdf` and `beamer-4.pdf`).

All you have to do is to use create the "main" presentation using the standard `\includegraphics` command (with appropriate settings) to include the four first pages using the `page=1` option (to extract the first page of each presentation), and `\href` to turn the images into hyperlinks. So, the general command would look something like (in the example below I also added a frame with `\fbox`, but this is optional).

```
\href{beamer-1.pdf}{\includegraphics[page=1,width=.8\linewidth]{beamer-1}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Four presentations}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.45\textheight][t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\fbox{\href{beamer-1.pdf}{\includegraphics[page=1,width=.8\linewidth]{beamer-1}}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c][0.45\textheight][t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\fbox{\href{beamer-1.pdf}{\includegraphics[page=1,width=.8\linewidth]{beamer-2}}}
\end{minipage}\par
\begin{minipage}[c][0.45\textheight][t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\fbox{\href{beamer-1.pdf}{\includegraphics[page=1,width=.8\linewidth]{beamer-3}}}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c][0.45\textheight][t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\fbox{\href{beamer-1.pdf}{\includegraphics[page=1,width=.8\linewidth]{beamer-4}}}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

where each image is hyperlinked to the corresponding presentation.

For completeness, here are the four documents used to produce the four PDFs:

#### `beamer1.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\title{First presentation}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### `beamer2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{Second presentation}
\author{The Buthor}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### `beamer3.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{Third presentation}
\author{The Cuthor}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### `beamer4.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\title{Fourth presentation}
\author{The Duthor}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Test frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The possibility to return to the main presentation can be achieved using a beamer button in the subsidiary presentations and the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism.

Comment: Do we need to extract first page of each presentation in another file? Is not adding option `page=1` in `\includegraphics` enough? I don't know if this option includes the whole child presentation in master one or just takes selected pages.

Comment: @Ignasi You're absolutely right. There's no need to extract the first pages first. Thanks for your useful suggestion. I've updated my answer incorporating it.

Comment: @Gonzalo thanks!. That was great!. Would it be possible that when I click on each presentation it zooms out to full screen in an animated way. I mean it slowly enlarges until it reaches the full screen. And then when it finishes again it comes back to the minimized size in an animated way slowly.